# Second opinion on edits

Tags: discussion

I searched for LibreOffice on App Store and I think the only thing under that name was a paid imitation product and not what is meant when LibreOffice is mentioned in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/158116/290197) answer.

[image]

So I edited the answer with what I *think* are the right (non-copycat) versions of OpenOffice and LibreOffice.

Since there may be more imitation products, and since I am not a regular user of OpenOffice nor LibreOffice, I would appreciate if someone could double check the edits to ensure they're not inaccurate.

Note: the URLs are the main thing I'm concerned about - just ensuring I actually got the right software (and not imitation software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. It's usually a good idea to add links to answers if people just mention applications, so thanks for that.

In the specific case, LibreOffice Vanilla actually *is* LibreOffice. From the description in the store:

> LibreOffice Vanilla is based directly on the LibreOffice source code from The Document Foundation. It is recommended for users who want the convenience of installing from the App Store and getting automatic updates, compared to manually downloading and installing from The Document Foundation.

So to make a really good edit on the mentioned answer you could reference both versions and explain the difference.

Comment: Thanks for this, that's an interesting case. Guess they've gotta make a little back somehow. I attributed you in the edit message, but please let me know if you'd like a more visible attribution (since you did the work to figure it out).

Comment: @stevec Fine for me